# Limit Batch Size in Apache Spark 3.0 Structured Streaming - MicroBatchStream

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am writing a custom structured streaming source and can't figure out how batch sizes can be limited. The new `MicroBatchStream` interface provides the `planInputPartitions` method that gets called with the return value of `latestOffset` as end Offset. It then returns a partitioning of the data up to the provided latest offset to be processed in a single batch.

When I start a new streaming query this results in an enormously large first batch as all historic data gets crammed into a single batch.

I already tried manually limiting the batch size by gradually increasing the latestOffset depending on what has already been committed. When restarting a query from a checkpoint, however, this fails as nothing has been committed yet.

Is there a (obvious) way of limiting streaming batch sizes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [SupportsAdmissionControl](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/sql/connector/read/streaming/SupportsAdmissionControl.java) interface for this purpose. This gives you the `Offset latestOffset(Offset startOffset, ReadLimit limit);` method that allows you to get the `startOffset` which is actually the `endOffset` of the previous batch. This way you can apply the size limit before you return the `latestOffset` response when you calculate it. Depending on your needs, you don't necessarily need to use the `ReadLimit` parameter - in our case we just have a predefined threshold which we use. The important part for you is the `startOffset` parameter.

Then, `planInputPartitions` will be called with the correct start and end offsets, which was caluclated using your size limit.

You can see an example for that in Kafka DataSource implmentation - see in [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.2.1/external/kafka-0-10-sql/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/kafka010/KafkaMicroBatchStream.scala#L114).